# Visual Basic: How to use timer properly

Tags: visual-studio, vba

I'm trying to write a simple program that could perform some tasks at specified time.

Here's what I have:

```
    If (TimeOfDay = "06:12:50") Then
        MsgBox(TimeOfDay)
    End If
    If (TimeOfDay = "06:13:58") Then
        MsgBox(TimeOfDay)
    End If
```

This code is placed inside Timer1_Tick, I set time interval - 1000 and it works OK, I get TimeOfDay value in MsgBox when current time is equal to my specified time.

But what should I do to make it work dynamically? For example: I want to type TIME value via TextBox and pass it to Timer1_Tick I need to do it as many times as I want so everytime current time matches with my specified hour,minute,second it would work, but I don't know where I have to put my code, because if I place code in while loop and in Time_Ticker1 it runs while loop every second and UI crashes immediately.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting a Windows Scheduled event of `MSG` to yourself using the `AT` command line? The operating system timer/scheduler, dialog, storage and queue are already there and the `MSG` can optionally be dismissed if there is no one to receive it within a set amount of time. Example to send the time at 06:12:15 run the following into a command shell.

```
AT 06:12:15 msg %USERNAME% It is 06:12:15 am
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I think my case is a little bit difficult but I didn't want to make my question appear to big. The thing is that I use telescope which is connected with my PC and I have developer components installed in visual express where I can control my telescope using built-in functions, and I want to make my telescope to point to different stars in different times that means I need to specify hour, minute, sec and coordinates for every star. What would be your suggestion?